# 500 error when trying to access page behind login credentials

Tags: authentication, web-scraping, python-requests

Can anyone see why this is returning 500 from the server?

If I remove the header information I get a 403, I can access the normally by logging in and then navigating to the page. However, if I am logged out and I try access the url directly, I get a white screen, doesn't even try to load.

Any fixes or alternatives?

```
import requests
import cred

header = {
"User-Agent": '"Chromium";v="116", "Not)A;Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="116"'
}

payload={
    'username':cred.username,
    'pass':cred.password
}

loginUrl = "https://gol.gg/user/login/"

secureUrl='https://gol.gg/premium/champion-synergy/162/season-ALL/split-ALL/tournament-ALL/'


with requests.session() as s:
    s.post(loginUrl, headers=header, data=payload)
    r=s.get(secureUrl,headers=header)    
    print(r)
```